# grep a keyword from Mplayer output and send the rest to file

Tags: terminal, grep, stdout, mplayer, tee

I am using mplayer. I want to send everything to a log file (/tmp/server.log), but I want the Volume output to be written to the terminal. I have seen that there is a way to split the output with tee, but I can't seem to get it to work. This is what I have so far:

```
$mplayer /path/to/song.wav 1>tee /tmp/server.log | grep Volume  2> /tmp/server.log
```

I want ALL of the stdout and stderr to go to the log file, but only the lines with Volume from stdout to be written to the terminal. Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using `bash` and that "Volume" is not a word that appears on stderr:

```
 $ mplayer /path/to/song.wav 2>&1 | tee -a /tmp/server.log | grep -F Volume
```

This combines the stdout and stderr from mplayer (`2>&1`), appends (note the `-a` to `/tmp/server.log` and `grep`'s all lines for the word `Volume`.

Comment: There's still some output, other than Volume lines that are slipping through.  Is there another output I'm not aware of and not catching?

Comment: @MrUser what is the actual output that you are seeing? I did not try this with `mplayer`, just with `{ echo "Volume 11" ; echo "error" 1>&2; } | tee ....`

Comment: The new output looks something like this: 

Line1: Volume: 9 %

Line2: A:  12.0 (12.0) of 104.0 (01:44.0)  0.2% 

The second line isn't the worst thing in the world, but at this point it would be an exercise to see if I could get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Assuming `bash`

```
$ mplayer /path/to/song.wav 2>> /tmp/server.log | tee -a /tmp/server.log | grep Volume
```

here I am first appending `stderr` to file and passing only `stdout` to `tee` and using grep from there.

This removes Anthon's assumption of Volume not in stderr.